# Apache, PHP and running programs - How does one multi thread this communication?

Tags: php, c++, multithreading, apache

So, let's say we have an Apache server with `PHP` at the ready and a webpage that does some calculations for the client. These calculations must be done via a separate (but in the same machine) executable that is running on loop waiting for connections. This works just fine if only one person ever accessed this page at once, but that expectation is unrealistic.

Assuming:

*A) Both the `PHP` page and the program (`C++`) can be modified as required.*

*B) I have an unknown number of cores, and wish to be flexible about how many are being used. (If it's notably easier, this can be concreted at setup.*

*C) Once begun within the executable, the calculations are linear and cannot be multi-threaded themselves.*

*D) Running more than one executable is fine, and can make a middle man if necessary.*

My question is: **What method should I use to ensure `Apache` can spread the workload around all cores in the event of multiple page requests at once?**